# Particle in a box : What is the conservative force?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential-energy

The particle in a box model assigns a value of zero to the potential energy $U(x)$ of the system throughout the interval $0 < x < L $, because the value of the potential energy is constant in the said interval. As the walls are impenetrable, $U(x) = \infty$ for $x \ge L$ and $x \le 0$

Potential energy is a property of a system and not of a particle. My guess is that the system in consideration here is the particle and whatever is setting up the impenetrable walls. Strictly, a potential energy function can only be established if there is a conservative force acting in between members of the system, so what would the force be in this case? And how does it set up a potential energy function that is independent of the particle's position in the interval $ x \in (0,L)$?

Comment: It's a free particle in that interval, no potential energy function at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a model problem to learn solving techniques.

In practice, you cannot realise such a situation.

Comment: Thank you. Does this also apply to models like the particle in a well of finite height?

Comment: @Cross Of course, all these models of perfectly localised walls, even of finite height, of perfectly zero potential etc. etc. are not physical, just exercises. And above all, one dimensional would really mean, infinite in the two other dimension and perfectly uniform,  that is,  absolutely no dependance in the two other dimensions.  Not **zero thickness** in the other directions, **infinite** ! And also, the potential should have existed unchanged forever in the past...

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help once again. Quantum mechanics is quite challenging to grasp.